# Activar efecto javascript cuando esta en el centro de la pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, script

Tengo este efecto en javascript.

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#aaa',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 1,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
  to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(.75);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Y el efecto que crea esta reproducido también en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72tkyn40/17760/)

Lo tengo usando ya y funcional, el problema es que necesito otros 3 y ademas que se active solo cuando se hace scroll hasta la ventana, se que se puede hacer con scrollmagic, pero no tengo ni idea como hacerlo. alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: No acabo de entender el problema: ¿Quieres que indique el porcentaje de scroll usado? ¿No puedes simplemente usar los eventos `scroll`?

Comment: Hola, disculpa que tardara, he estado algo enfermo y no he podido responder antes. Al final lo solucione jugando un poco con javascript y buscando mucho. Lo que necesitaba es que se calculara cuando habia scrolleado hasta el punto que yo queria y ahi se iniciara la animacion del circulo.

Comment: Veo que al final usaste el evento scroll... Gracias por poner una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada, al final lo he solucionado asi:

```
 var werwirsind = $('#werwirsind'),
    abstand_nach_oben = werwirsind.offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var abstand_gescrollt = $(this).scrollTop() + 100;
    if (abstand_nach_oben <= abstand_gescrollt) {
        bar1.animate(.9);
        bar2.animate(.7);
        bar3.animate(.6);
        bar4.animate(.75);
        $(this).unbind('scroll');
    }

});
```